# Choosing Azure services

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am running a very small ASP.Net application with minimal load and minimal database usage (max 50 MB). Though I want the latency to be small and the irritating delay when the application starts from hibernation, can that be dealt with?

To my actual question. The web application is on a D1 Shared plan and the database is on B Basic. I get an invoice each month at about 140 SEK ($16) even though there are no traffic.

Should I consider moving from Azure, and if so where?
Is there any choices in Azure I can make to make it cheaper?

Answer (score 1):

Azure will charge you for the capacity to run a service, in your case some space on a database and four hours of CPU time for web hosting. You are charged for the amount of time you have had a service provisioned and the bandwidth it consumes.

You could move to the shared or the free tier, which would reduce your performance and costs.

You could also reengineer your application to use Azure Storage Tables, which will make data storage considerably cheaper, but does require some work to transform.

You may or may not find a better provider out there, all you can do is shop around and see what exists that fits your requirements. Unfortunately such recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow.